# Audit Trail/Log when performing stock quantity adjustments

Tags: virtocommerce

Are stock quantity adjustments logged/recorded?

One can adjust stock quantity by using Commerce Manager -> Fulfillment module -> Inventory tab -> double click on an entry in the list -> click **Edit quantity** button

A form will appear to facilitate the quantity adjustment. Given this scenario, a dishonest employee at our Fulfillment Centre stole an Item from the warehouse and adjusted the quantity of the Item in the system to reflect a lesser quantity than it should. At the end of the week, an officer from the management will visit the warehouse and perform a stock count against the system and will find everything tally since the dishonest employee had already tampered with the system.

My question is, does the system keep a log of events where quantity has been adjusted and records the value of the adjustment? There is a database table named **__OperationLogs** that logs activities of the **Inventory** database table but it only specified that the table has been *Modified*. It didn't specify WHAT has been modified. The dishonest employee could easily dispute that he only modified other fields, not the *Quantity* field. We need a *smoking gun* to proof the guilt of the employee.

The same could be said to Price List. A dishonest employee with access to Price List could modify the selling price of an item to an absurdly low price and purchase it. After that he/she re-modify the selling price back to its original value.

To what length does Virto Commerce play a role in deterring larceny by logging activities at a more granular level for sensitive areas? Stock Quantity and Selling Price are considered sensitive because they affect the profit of a business.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is a good question. We should track the reason for stock replenishing especially since you can pick it in UI. I'll have to talk to developer responsible for Inventory module to get the reasoning it wasn't done.

Regarding the overall audit trail, we currently have so called change interceptors. One example is: AuditChangeInterceptor. Which is fired every time the object is modified and just before or after the save. That interceptor is passed current and previous values for the object and you can then save that information to the log file. So mode detailed (not just date and object) log can be saved regarding the modifications.

We also implemented more advanced logging system for one of the clients and it should be incorporated to the product shortly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: In the **Edit quantity** form, there's this dropdown field **Reason** which has 3 options (Theft, Damaged, Transfer). Does this field in any way saved into the database after the form is submitted? If so, which database table is it saved to?

Answer (score 0):

It is supposed to be stored in logging. Logging is still in progress. So Interceptors is the option to store InStockQuantity value changes and reason for now.